Azure Logic App Function call for non json body
I am Configuring logic app in one of compose action i have below output but its not json format from this output i need AlertID value alone since its not json format functions are showing invalid format error , can some one help me to fix this


:azure: :alert: 
*Non-Prod Alert: RuleCpupercetange*
*Severity*: Sev4
*Timestamp*: 2024-10-10T17:55:18.5144302Z 
*Alert Id*: ```/subscriptions/32476574-bf58-4703-96d9-4378327845/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/629bd98a-f9b5-c79a-75b1-b807b48d0002```
Click here to find the code 
*****************************************************
*Affected resource: W008ssaltmost* 
*Resource modified by:unknown@gmail.com*
*****************************************************
*Select a response:*, with interactive elements




Can you provide more info? Like, what expression have you used to try and get your result? What’s the exact error? Screenshots help and the expression as text (not an image) is also preferred.

chunk(string(outputs('Compose')), indexOf(outputs('Compose'), 'Alert Id')) this is the function i tried to get the value, goal is i need to set the variable AlertID = /subscriptions/32476574-bf58-4703-96d9-4378327845/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/629bd98a-f9b5-c79a-75b1-b807b48d0002

This expression will do it for you ...
split(variables('Text'), '```')[1]

... with a huge caveat and that is that the data will stay as is and not deviate from what you've provided.
Replace variables('Text') with whatever you're supplying to the Compose step.
